# Simplify Array Duplicate Element in Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can we find the count of duplicate elements in a `multidimensional array`,

**I have an array like this:**

```
Array 
      ( 
          [0] => Array 
              ( 
                  [brti] => 29 
              ) 
          [1] => Array 
              ( 
                  [voda] => 6 
              ) 
          [2] => Array 
              ( 
                  [btel] => 8 
              ) 
          [3] => Array 
              ( 
                  [btel] => 10 
              ) 
      )
```

**Question:** How to simplify the structure of array, i mean can be counting the value if there is indicate that have same key ?

**just like this:**

```
Array 
  ( 
      [0] => Array 
          ( 
              [brti] => 29 
          ) 
      [1] => Array 
          ( 
              [voda] => 6 
          ) 
      [2] => Array 
          ( 
              [btel] => 18 
          ) 
  )
```

**So far, i've tried this way, but it didn't help me**. `My array is store in $test`

```
    $test = [sample array]

    $count = array();
    foreach ($test as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value as $k => $val) {
            if (isset($count[$val])) {
                ++$count[$val];
            } else {
                $count[$value] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    print_r($count);
```

Comment: you also want to sum the value of duplicate key... which you haven't mention but can be seen clear in your example

Comment: What do you mean by "simplified"?

Comment: Yes sir, i mean simplified with sum the value of same key @SayedMohdAli

Comment: i mean simplified with sum the value of same key @YongQuan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in very simple way,

```
$test = [];
foreach ($array as $value)
{
    foreach ($value as $k => $v)
    {
        // $test[$k] = ($test[$k] ?? 0); // initialised if not php 7+
        $test[$k] = (empty($test[$k]) ? 0: $test[$k]); //  below php 7 
        $test[$k] += $v;
    }
}

print_r($test);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [brti] => 29
    [voda] => 6
    [btel] => 18
)
```

Working [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ef1772ed55c36f0a207098e42263adadf73dbc12).

Comment: Parse error, syntax error, unexpected '??' sir @Rahul Meshram

Comment: Check now. that was syntax of php 7+, you might be using php 7 below.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$array = [
    "0" => ["brti" => 29],
    "1" => ["voda" => 6],
    "2" => ["btel" => 8],
    "3" => ["btel" => 10],
];
$final = array();

array_walk_recursive($array, function($item, $key) use (&$final){
    $final[$key] = isset($final[$key]) ?  $item + $final[$key] : $item;
});
print_r($final);

    });
```

[check demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/99310505217287be032db7d2aee1f837aaf14292)